# Redirecting SUBDOMAIN to a FOLDER using MOD Rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain, redirect

I hope someone can help me

I am trying to redirect NON www traffic requests from

USER.domain.com/FOLDER/somethinghere

to

domain.com/newFOLDER/USER/somethinghere

i tried

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.*).domain.com
RewriteRule ^FOLDER/%1/(.*) http://domain.com/newFOLDER/%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

but the redirection goes to

domain.com/newFOLDER/somethinghere

can some offer help?

thanks! Mark

Answer (score 1):

It should be like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^FOLDER/(.*)$ http://domain.com/newFOLDER/%1/$1 [R=301,L,NC]
```

Comment: smooth and cool anubhava! thanks. can i bother you bit more? how can i add conditional redirect, i mean to use this redirection only if file is not found?

Comment: @mark: I edited my answer to reflect change based on your comment. Now it will redirect **ONLY** if file/directory is not found. And if you find this answer helpful, pls mark this accepted to close this Q&A.